# How to prevent sorting on specific table column - DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I don't want to sort my action column, so I did :

```
<th class="no-sort" >Actions</th>
```

and update my JS like this

```
$('table').DataTable( {
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "Filter": true,
    "Info": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "searchHighlight": true,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSort": false,
        "aTargets": ["no-sort"]
    }]
} );
```

I still see that it is sortable. ‍♂️

[image]

**How do I stop that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct property is `bSortable`, not `bSort`. See the [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
  "bSortable": false,
  "aTargets": ["no-sort"]
}]
```

Also note that from your use of `aoColumnDefs` it appears you're using a very old version of DataTables; at least 5 years old in fact. I'd suggest upgrading it when possible.